# when file moved/renamed - what's the difference between java RAF and File 

Tags: java, java-io, inode

I only want to discuss about this in java/linux context.

```
RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile("test.log", "r");
```

VS

```
File file = new File("test.log");
```

After the creation, we start reading the file to the end.

1. In java.io.File case, it will throw IOException when reading the file if you mv or delete the physical file prior to the file reading.

   ```
   public void readIOFile() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       File file = new File("/tmp/test.log");
       System.out.print("file created"); // convert byte into char
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       while (true) {
           char[] buffer = new char[1024];
           FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
           fr.read(buffer);
           System.out.println(buffer);
       }
   }
   ```
2. But in RandomFileAccess case, if you mv or delete the physical file prior to the file reading, it will finish reading the file without errors/exceptions.

   ```
   public void readRAF() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       File file = new File("/tmp/test.log");
       RandomAccessFile rand = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
       System.out.println("file created"); // convert byte into char
       while (true) {
           System.out.println(file.lastModified());
           System.out.println(file.length());
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           System.out.println("finish sleeping");
           int i = (int) rand.length();
           rand.seek(0); // Seek to start point of file
           for (int ct = 0; ct < i; ct++) {
               byte b = rand.readByte(); // read byte from the file
               System.out.print((char) b); // convert byte into char
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Can anyone explain to me why ? Is there anything to do with file's inode?

Comment: java.io.File does not throw any IOExceptions. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP thanks for pointing it out. I should have pasted my test code here at the 1st place. I meant IOExceptions gets thrown during the file reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS based file system services such as creating folders, files, verifying the permissions, changing file names etc., are provided by the java.io.File class.

The java.io.RandomAccessFile class provides random access to the records that are stored in a data file. Using this class, reading and writing , manipulations to the data can be done. One more flexibility is that it can read and write primitive data types, which helps in structured approach in handling data files.

Unlike the input and output stream classes in java.io, RandomAccessFile is used for both reading and writing files. RandomAccessFile does not inherit from InputStream or OutputStream. It implements the DataInput and DataOutput interfaces.

Comment: can you be more specific how does this explain why case 1 and 2 are above behaving differently?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `RandomAccessFile` or say, `InputStream` and many other java IO facilities, File is just an immutable handle that you drag from time to time when you need to do filesystem gateway actions. You may think of it as the reference: File instance is **pointing** to some specified **path**. On the other hand `RandomAccessFile` have notion of path only at construction time: it goes to the specified path, opens file and acquires **file system descriptor** -- you may think of it as an unique id of a given file, which do not changes on move and some other operations -- and uses this id throughout it's lifetime to address file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no evidence here that you have moved or renamed the file *at all.*

If you did thatt from outside the program, clearly it is just a timing issue.

If you rename a file before you try to open it with the old name, it will fail. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score -1):

One of the main difference is, File can not have control over write or read directly, it requires IO streams to do that. Where as RAF, we can write or read the files.

Comment: I updated my title here, I am more looking for why we have the difference between them when the physical file is moved or deleted.